Botones desplegable de acciones no funcionan cuando adiciono un nuevo registro a una tabla con Laravel Inertia y Vue
Tengo el problema que cuando estoy adicionando un nuevo registro usando Laravel, Inertia y Vue el registro adicionado se adiciona a mi tabla visualmente pero el boton de accion desplegable que contiene las acciones de eliminar y editar del registro nuevo adicionado no funcionan desplegando la accion pero el boton de los registros que estaban ya en la tabla siguen funcionando. Pero si doy F5 y refresco la página funcionan todos los botones.
Esto tendra que ver con algo en especifico que necesito adicionar a mi funcion en el frontend para que se haga un reload o algo parecido? Pregunto esto porque cuando realizo un update o un eliminar los botones de acciones de las filas de la tabla siguen funcionando pero solo me sucede el problema cuando se adiciona uno nuevo:
metodo del controller para adicionar registros nuevos:
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $product = new Product();
        $product->title = $request->title;
        $product->price = $request->price;
        $product->quantity = $request->quantity;
        $product->description = $request->description;
        $product->category_id = $request->category_id;
        $product->brand_id = $request->brand_id;

        if ($request->quantity > 0)
            $product->inStock = 1;

        $product->save();

        //check if product has images upload
        if ($request->hasFile('product_images')) {
            $productImages = $request->file('product_images');
            foreach ($productImages as $image) {
                // Generate a unique name for the image using timestamp and random string
                $uniqueName = time() . '-' . Str::random(10) . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                // Store the image in the public folder with the unique name
                $image->move('product_images', $uniqueName);
                // Create a new product image record with the product_id and unique name
                ProductImage::create([
                    'product_id' => $product->id,
                    'image' => 'product_images/' . $uniqueName,
                ]);
            }
        }

        return to_route('admin.products.index')->with('success', 'Product created successfully.')->with('prueba', 'Esto fue una prueba');

   }

Este es el metodo en el frontend:
    const AddProduct = async () => {

    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("title", title.value);
    formData.append("price", price.value);
    formData.append("quantity", quantity.value);
    formData.append("description", description.value);
    formData.append("brand_id", brand_id.value);
    formData.append("category_id", category_id.value);

    // Append product images to the FormData
    for (const image of productImages.value) {
        formData.append("product_images[]", image.raw);
    }

    try {
        await router.post("products/store", formData, {

            preserveState: true,
            onSuccess: (page) => {

                dialogVisible.value = false;
                resetFormData();

                Swal.fire({
                    toast: true,
                    icon: "success",
                    position: "top-end",
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    title: page.props.flash.success,
                    showCloseButton: true,
                });


            },
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};

Y esta es la tabla que tengo:
<table class="w-full text-sm text-left text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
                    <thead
                        class="text-xs text-gray-700 uppercase bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400"
                    >
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col" class="px-4 py-3">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="px-4 py-3">Category</th>
                            <th scope="col" class="px-4 py-3">Brand</th>
                            <th scope="col" class="px-4 py-3">Quantity</th>
                            <th scope="col" class="px-4 py-3">Price</th>
                            <th scope="col" class="px-4 py-3">Stock</th>
                            <th scope="col" class="px-4 py-3">Publish</th>
                            <th scope="col" class="px-4 py-3">
                                <span class="sr-only">Actions</span>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr v-for="(product, index) in products" :key="product.id" class="border-b dark:border-gray-700">
                            <th scope="row" class="px-4 py-3 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                                {{ product.title }}
                            </th>
                            <td class="px-4 py-3">
                                {{ product.category.name }}
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-4 py-3">
                                {{ product.brand.name }}
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-4 py-3">
                                {{ product.quantity }}
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-4 py-3">{{ product.price }}</td>
                            <td class="px-4 py-3">
                                <span v-if="product.inStock == 1"
                                    class="bg-green-100 text-green-800 text-xs font-medium mr-2 px-2.5 py-0.5 rounded dark:bg-green-900 dark:text-green-300"
                                    >inStock
                                </span>
                                <span
                                    v-else
                                    class="bg-red-100 text-red-800 text-xs font-medium mr-2 px-2.5 py-0.5 rounded dark:bg-red-900 dark:text-red-300"
                                    >Out of Stock
                                </span>
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-4 py-3">
                                <button
                                    v-if="product.published == 1"
                                    type="button"
                                    class="px-3 py-2 text-xs font-medium text-center text-white bg-green-700 rounded-lg hover:bg-green-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-green-300 dark:bg-green-600 dark:hover:bg-green-700 dark:focus:ring-green-800"
                                >
                                    Published
                                </button>
                                <button
                                    v-else
                                    type="button"
                                    class="px-3 py-2 text-xs font-medium text-center text-white bg-red-700 rounded-lg hover:bg-red-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-red-300 dark:bg-red-600 dark:hover:bg-red-700 dark:focus:ring-red-800"
                                >
                                    UnPublished
                                </button>
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-4 py-3 flex items-center justify-end">
                                <button
                                    :id="`${product.id}-button`"
                                    :data-dropdown-toggle="`${product.id}`"
                                    class="inline-flex items-center p-0.5 text-sm font-medium text-center text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-800 rounded-lg focus:outline-none dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:text-gray-100"
                                    type="button"
                                >
                                    <svg
                                        class="w-5 h-5"
                                        aria-hidden="true"
                                        fill="currentColor"
                                        viewbox="0 0 20 20"
                                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                    >
                                        <path
                                            d="M6 10a2 2 0 11-4 0 2 2 0 014 0zM12 10a2 2 0 11-4 0 2 2 0 014 0zM16 12a2 2 0 100-4 2 2 0 000 4z"
                                        />
                                    </svg>
                                </button>
                                <div
                                    :id="`${product.id}`"
                                    class="hidden z-10 w-44 bg-white rounded divide-y divide-gray-100 shadow dark:bg-gray-700 dark:divide-gray-600"
                                >
                                    <ul
                                        class="py-1 text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200"
                                        :aria-labelledby="`${product.id}-button`"
                                    >
                                        <li>
                                            <a
                                                href="#"
                                                @click="
                                                    openEditModal(product)
                                                "
                                                class="block py-2 px-4 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white"
                                                >Edit</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <div class="py-1">
                                        <a
                                            href="#"
                                            @click="
                                                deleteProduct(
                                                    product,
                                                    index
                                                )
                                            "
                                            class="block py-2 px-4 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:text-gray-200 dark:hover:text-white"
                                            >Delete</a
                                        >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

Ademas dejo una foto de la tabla para señalar que tipo de botones me refiero:


Encontre la solución al problema. Todo estaba en que tenia en el onSuccess de la función AddProduct el preserveState: true y esto evitaba que se actualizara el estado de la página, por lo que lo cambie a false y media oro funcionó perfecto y la función quedo de la siguiente forma:
    const AddProduct = async () => {

    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("title", title.value);
    formData.append("price", price.value);
    formData.append("quantity", quantity.value);
    formData.append("description", description.value);
    formData.append("brand_id", brand_id.value);
    formData.append("category_id", category_id.value);

    // Append product images to the FormData
    for (const image of productImages.value) {
        formData.append("product_images[]", image.raw);
    }

    try {
        await router.post("products/store", formData, {
           
            onSuccess: (page) => {
                dialogVisible.value = false;
                resetFormData();

                Swal.fire({
                    toast: true,
                    icon: "success",
                    position: "top-end",
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    title: page.props.flash.success,
                    showCloseButton: true,
                });
            },  
            preserveScroll: true,
            preserveState: false,
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

};

